# Best way to design iPhone interface

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface

In terms of interface design in Interface Builder or Photoshop, what does everyone do? Ie. setting gradients as backgrounds, using pngs as icons. Whats the easiest way to do this sort of stuff? All through code or what?

Comment: I use one of these: http://www.uistencils.com/

Comment: They look really cool. But i am not arty so i rarely sketch stuff out, although i appreciate that my app needs to look awesome, not just function correctly!

Comment: The best tool is whatever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [MockApp](http://mockapp.com/).